# How to use Amazon ELB application stickiness, when have no control over server response?

Tags: amazon-elb

We are using Amazon ELB for our servers that provide REST APIs, and we want our client applications to be able to use the ELB application stickiness policy to process some REST APIs.  Some of the APIs must be done as a transaction (multiple steps or APIs involved) and therefore, must be handled by the same server behind ELB.  We are not able to change the responses sent by the server to include a session ID.  How can we handle this since ELB only provides its AWSELB cookie if the server includes a "set-cookie" with the session ID cookie name specified in ELB?

We do have control of the client applications.  We can modify the HTTP requests they make to the servers (through ELB).

Answer (score 1):

["The load balancer only inserts a new stickiness cookie if the application response includes a new application cookie"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application) is only applicable to application-controlled session stickiness.

Configure your balancer for [duration-based session stickiness](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-duration).